# Java 8 List from String and List of String

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I want to generate a list of strings, comprising id and external ids, from a list of Bean.

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private List<String> externalIds;
}
```

I got it using the below code, but here I need to do the stream twice.

```
List<User> references = new ArrayList();
Stream.concat(references.stream().map(User::getId),
references.stream().map(User::getExternalIds).flatMap(Collection::stream))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there any better way to rewrite this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Stream.concat` inside the `flatMap` operation:

```
references.stream()
        .flatMap(user -> Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(user.getId()),
            user.getExternalIds().stream()
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this solution works, the only issue is if externalIds is null, then it will throw an error. I can initialize the list in bean to prevent this. Any other way do you think?

Comment: Allowing null collections, maps or arrays are usually bad to work with, because you need to add a lot of null checks. Using an empty collection/list/set, map or array is almost always better.

Comment: `collect(Collectors.toList())`can be replaced by `toList()`

Comment: @ciccioska indeed, if you're using Java 16 or later

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
references.stream()
  .flatMap(u -> Stream.of(List.of(u.getId()), u.getExternalIds()))
  .flatMap(List::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: .flatMap(List::stream) is not working , its giving error  ""Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context""

Comment: I think that Bohemian tried to let the `map` step return a `Stream<List<String>>`, but it's a `Stream<Stream<List<String>>>`. You'd need to use `flatMap(Function.identity())` to get a `Stream<List<String>>` back, then `flatMap(List::stream)` to get a `Stream<String>`.

Comment: @Rob I did get a little tangled there. Thanks for the hint, but you can avoid `flatMap(Function.identity())` by `flatMap` instead of `map` first up. See latest edit.

Comment: @Bohemian you're right, the `map` returned a `Stream`, that can of course be done with `flatMap` immediately.

Comment: @Rob I'm going to go out on a limb and say this is more readable, because it first uplifts `id` to be the same type as `externalIds`, then takes care of business.

Comment: In terms of readability, if we compare with the accepted answer, we have here `Stream.of(List.of(u.getId()), u.getExternalIds())` followed by `flatMap(List::stream)` vs. just `Stream.concat(Stream.of(user.getId()), user.getExternalIds().stream())` without the need for `flatMap()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 16+ you can do it using `mapMulti`.  This essentially intercepts each item in the stream and replaces it with other items. It avoids re-streaming and flatmapping.  Since the nature of the stream(i.e. type) is being changed from `User` to `String`, the witness before `mapMulti` is required.

- add the `user id` in the stream.
- then add each `external id` in the stream for that user

```
List<String> results = references.stream()
        .<String>mapMulti((user, consumer) -> {
            consumer.accept(user.getId());
            for (String id : user.getExternalIds()) {
                consumer.accept(id);
            }
        }).toList();
```